# WPF combobox multi bind on properties of object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource Combobox}"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Height="25" Foreground="Black">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="Name"/>
            <Binding Path="Identifier"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

I'm trying to bind the `ComboBoxItems` to show both the Name and the `Identifier` property of my Details list, on which this `ComboBox.ItemSource` should bind. How can I do this?

Basically the `ItemSource` should bind to a list of objects (called Details) and each `ComboBoxItem` should show the `Name` + `Identifier` property for each of those objects.

Comment: Your MultiBinding should be in `DataTemplate` NOT ItemsSource. `ItemsSource` should be `ItemsSource="{Binding Details}"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have this instead:

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Details}"
    Style="{StaticResource Combobox}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="180" 
    Height="25" 
    Foreground="Black"
    >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Name"/>
                        <Binding Path="Identifier"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```